# Windows 2019 Registry Values Keep Reverting (Windows Defender)

Tags: registry, group-policy, windows-defender

I keep running into this issue with Windows Defender policies. As far as I know, I am only having issues with Defender, no other policies.

I have disabled "Turn off routine remediation" and "Turn off real time protection" in the local group policy. In theory, that should change the values of "DisableRoutinelyTakingAction" and "DisableRealtimeMonitoring" from 1 to 0 in the Windows Registry. However, the values are still 1. I can manually change these values to 0, but it reverts back to 1 each time I restart.

Has anyone had this issue before or know how to remediate? I don't see any other group policies that could be overriding it. Could it be something inside Defender itself?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!